# Debugging TypeScript in VSCode with Asp.Net Core 3.1

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying the approach of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628397/debug-typescript-in-vscode-with-asp-net-core) but it works only if I use the "debugger" command in typescript code, but not with breakpoints.

Here is my lauch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "ASP.Net Core & Browser",
            "configurations": [
                ".NET Core Launch (web)",
                "Launch Chrome"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/MyApp.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "https://localhost:5001",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/wwwroot"
        }
    ]
}
```

### update tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "preserveWhitespaces": "off",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "esnext"
  }
}
```

### Solution, after tHeSiD answer:

### lauch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "ASP.Net Core & Browser",
            "configurations": [
                ".NET Core Launch (web)",
                "Launch Chrome"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/MyApp.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            },
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:5000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/wwwroot",
            "sourceMaps": true
        }
    ]
}
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "preserveWhitespaces": "off",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "esnext"
  }
}
```

Comment: please post your tsconfig

Comment: @tHeSiD, donne!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For VSCode to catch breakpoints in your app, you need to use inline source maps or set the correct sourcemap path.

For me the best settings have been

```js
//TSCONFIG SETTINGS
"inlineSourceMap": true /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */,
"inlineSources": true /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */,
```

You need to remove `"sourceMap": true,` in your `tsconfig` if you want to use `"inlineSourceMap": true` NOT FROM LAUNCH.JSON!

```js
//LAUNCH.JSON Settings
"sourceMaps": true,
"outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"], // you need to set this according to your project config
```

This fixes most of the issues which are related to source maps on which VSCode relies on for Debugging TS Files.

Comment: Changes in the lauch.json is made in what configurarion?

Comment: I'm receiving property outfiles is not allowed

Comment: Oh i forgot it was the .net config, you can remove the out files entry and check

Comment: Did you add `"sourceMaps": true,` to both your configs in launch.json?

Comment: This was the problem. Gotcha!

Comment: After saving a change to the file, the debugger does not work anymore. :(